# Partial trace of quantum state in SymPy

Tags: sympy

Is there an easy way to get the partial trace of a quantum state in SymPy? Or do I need to create a custom `partial_trace` function?

In this example I would like to trace out the 2 qubits in the middle:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.quantum.gate import CNOT, CGate, H, Z
from sympy.physics.quantum.qapply import qapply
from sympy.physics.quantum.qubit import Qubit
from sympy.physics.quantum.circuitplot import CircuitPlot

a, b, c, d = var('a b c d', complex=True)

# create quantum circuit
qc = CGate((1,), Z(3), 2) * H(1) * CNOT(1, 0) * CNOT(2, 1) * CNOT(3, 2)

# display(CircuitPlot(qc, nqubits=4))

# create state
state = 1/2 * (
    a * (Qubit('0000') + Qubit('0010') + Qubit('0100') + Qubit('0110')) +
    b * (Qubit('0001') + Qubit('0011') + Qubit('0101') + Qubit('0111')) +
    c * (Qubit('1000') + Qubit('1010') + Qubit('1100') + Qubit('1110')) +
    d * (Qubit('1001') + Qubit('1011') + Qubit('1101') + Qubit('1111'))
)

# apply quantum circuit to state
result = qapply(qc * state)
```